# Are waitUntil of page.goto and page.waitForNavigation the same?

Tags: puppeteer

As far as I know both `page.goto` and  `page.waitForNavigation` accept  `waitUntil` as a parameter, is it just two ways to achieve the same results?

For example:

```
page.goto(url, {waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded'})
```

vs:

```
page.waitForNavigation(url, {waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded'})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On puppeteer version 1.19.0, [waitForNavigation](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.19.0/docs/api.md#pagewaitfornavigationoptions) **does not** accept an url. Usually waitForNavigation is used with a click, where clicking might cause a navigation in the browser.

Example:

```
const [response] = await Promise.all([
  page.waitForNavigation(), // The promise resolves after navigation has finished
  page.click('a.my-link'), // Clicking the link will indirectly cause a navigation
]);
```

It accepts options similar to `.goto()`, but that's all.

So,

- page.goto() will go to an url and wait for navigation.
- page.waitForNavigation() will only wait for navigation.

Comment: @md-abu-taher no solution to execute a wait based on url location content?